# Launching nautilus file browser launches gnome desktop, how to suppress it

Tags: gnome3, nautilus, i3

Currently I'm using `i3` window manager (but I guess that this applies to other non-standard window managers as well). Whenever I run nautilus it also starts a full screen desktop, which I have to close.

Possible solution is to start nautilus with: `nautilus --browser --no-desktop`, which solves this problem only partially, as sometimes nautilus is launched automatically by other applications and in this case it would be launched without `--browser --no-desktop` options.

Is there any gnome3 config option that allows me to suppress desktop launching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a `dconf` value that controls this. Run the following command to disable drawing of the desktop by Nautilus:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/237984/81372

Comment: This is a step in right direction, now if I call ``nautilus`` i don't get destop. But still some other app will launch nautilus with desktop.

Comment: @jb Mmh, that's strange. Unfortunately that's all I know, sorry.

Comment: Works perfectly for me

Comment: This simple command is essential for i3 window manager, where the gnome "desktop" otherwise overtakes the entire i3 workspace, making it unusable. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to turn off `show-desktop-icons` permanently, maybe because you also use another window manager or desktop such as GNOME or Unity you create a new `.desktop` file which specifies the command to use to open nautilus. For example, `~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
NotShowIn=Unity;GNOME
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nautilus --new-window --no-desktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

This only works if you are using an application launcher such as [i3-dmenu-desktop](http://build.i3wm.org/docs/i3-dmenu-desktop.html) which support the [desktop standard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries).

For example in `~/.config/i3/config` you could have any of the following:

```
bindsym $mod+space exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop
bindsym $mod+space exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop --dmenu='dmenu -i'
```

The example `.desktop` file above will show up in the launcher as "Files", as per the `Name` attribute. It will also show up as "files" if you are running with case insensitivity, `dmenu -i`.